# Can I force an element to finish it's animation immediately?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I have some code to show a UIView with a label as a notification.

```
self.not1cons.constant = 0
self.notificationLbl1.text = self.notification1

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0.3, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

       }, completion: { finsihed in

            self.not1cons.constant = -100

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 2.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {

                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

       }, completion: { finshed in

           })
       })
```

It start off-screen and descends in to view. It stays in place for a few seconds and returns to its original position off-screen. I need some code to make these chained animations happen instantly. Is this possible?

Comment: You are adding a `delay` of `2.0` and then complaining that there is a delay?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'happen instantly'? Do you know ahead of time that you want to make the animations finish immediately, or do you want to cancel the animations mid-animation?

Comment: It's kind of unclear, if I got it right, I agree with @matt note, why you are adding delay for the second animation?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself correctly, The animation is fine, however I would like a function to force these animations to execute instantly. like a dismiss function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this by manipulating the CAAnimations the system generates behind the scenes, but that is fairly tricky business, and not a great idea since it relies on undocumented details of the current implemention, which is risky.

Instead I'd suggest reworking your animations to use the new-to-iOS 10 
UIViewPropertyAnimator, which has support for pausing and resuming animations, as well as scrubbing them back and forth to arbitrary points.

I have a demo project on Gitub called [**UIViewPropertyAnimator-test**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIViewPropertyAnimator-test) that lets you scrub an animation back and forth using a slider. It is more complex than your need, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the cool library, but I just used a function to set their opacity to 0 instead.